# Is $A^TA$ invertible if each row of A sum to 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is a m by n matrix where n is less than m. We also know that the sum of each row of A is 1. Am I able to tell if $A^TA$ is invertible? If yes, how to prove this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if all rows are identical?

Answer (score 3):

No, for example consider the matrix which is 1 in the first column in every row and 0 otherwise. $A^TA$ is not invertible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

With the given conditions, $A^TA$ is invertible precisely when $\ker A=0$, that is the rank of $A$ is $n$. This is because $$A^TAx=0\iff \|Ax\|^2=x^TA^TAx=0\iff Ax=0$$ The fact that the rows of $A$ sum to $1$ is irrelevant.